# Android , HTC WIdget animations

Tags: android, widget

How is it possible to do animations on widgets like those that happen in HTC weather widgets?
What is the way t go about to do such animations?

Since app widgets are limited in their functionality, how can we achieve these ?

Kindly give your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use gif for achieving animation. Refer to [android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Movie.html) for this
You can also refer to [frame animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#frame-animation) guide of Android